# ntp daily time drift

Tags: date, time, ntp, drift

starting from about 2-3 weeks ago ntp lost its sync and since then it loses between 40 sec to 1 minute every day,
it then syncs this difference instantly, every day at around 9 pm.

/var/log/ntp.log :

```
 8 Jun 09:01:54 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 4001    
 8 Jun 09:18:57 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 0001    
 8 Jun 09:53:08 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 4001    
 8 Jun 10:10:14 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 0001    
 8 Jun 12:26:45 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 4001    
 8 Jun 12:43:51 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 0001    
 8 Jun 14:43:19 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 4001    
 8 Jun 15:00:23 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 0001    
 8 Jun 16:25:45 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 4001    
 8 Jun 16:42:49 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 0001    
 8 Jun 17:16:59 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 4001    
 8 Jun 17:34:05 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 0001    
 8 Jun 19:16:30 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 4001    
 8 Jun 19:33:33 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 0001    
 8 Jun 20:59:28 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10    
 8 Jun 21:17:43 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3    
 **8 Jun 21:33:19 ntpd[7688]: time reset -33.667071 s**    
 8 Jun 21:37:36 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10    
 8 Jun 21:38:40 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3    
 9 Jun 10:56:38 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 4001    
 9 Jun 11:13:41 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 0001    
 9 Jun 12:04:56 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 4001    
 9 Jun 13:47:20 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 0001    
 9 Jun 14:21:31 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 4001    
 9 Jun 14:38:37 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 0001    
 9 Jun 20:11:40 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 4001    
 9 Jun 20:45:48 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 0001    
 9 Jun 21:03:40 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10    
 9 Jun 21:21:35 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3    
 **9 Jun 21:54:16 ntpd[7688]: time reset -35.209243 s**    
 9 Jun 21:57:54 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10    
 9 Jun 21:59:00 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3    
10 Jun 20:57:04 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10    
10 Jun 21:03:59 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3    
**10 Jun 21:18:25 ntpd[7688]: time reset -36.757260 s**    
10 Jun 21:21:45 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10    
10 Jun 21:23:52 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3    
11 Jun 21:07:25 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10    
11 Jun 21:24:25 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3    
**11 Jun 21:40:52 ntpd[7688]: time reset -38.305589 s**    
11 Jun 21:44:29 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10    
11 Jun 21:45:33 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3    
12 Jun 08:37:43 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 4001    
12 Jun 08:50:34 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 0001    
12 Jun 21:01:10 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10    
12 Jun 21:07:53 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
**12 Jun 21:22:13 ntpd[7688]: time reset -39.854883 s**  
12 Jun 21:26:19 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
12 Jun 21:27:23 ntpd[7688]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
13 Jun 02:26:51 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
13 Jun 04:43:29 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
13 Jun 05:34:43 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
13 Jun 06:25:57 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
13 Jun 07:34:16 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
13 Jun 07:51:21 ntpd[7688]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
13 Jun 13:18:34 ntpd[7688]: ntpd exiting on signal 15  
13 Jun 13:21:51 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
13 Jun 13:21:51 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
13 Jun 13:23:57 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
13 Jun 21:10:58 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
13 Jun 21:27:09 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
**13 Jun 22:00:28 ntpd[6771]: time reset -41.396780 s**  
13 Jun 22:00:28 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
13 Jun 22:04:38 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
13 Jun 22:04:38 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
13 Jun 22:05:44 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
14 Jun 04:09:19 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
14 Jun 04:43:27 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
14 Jun 06:08:50 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
14 Jun 06:25:55 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
14 Jun 07:00:05 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
14 Jun 07:51:19 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
14 Jun 08:25:28 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
14 Jun 08:42:31 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
14 Jun 10:59:05 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
14 Jun 11:16:11 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
14 Jun 12:24:27 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
14 Jun 12:33:00 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
14 Jun 16:40:51 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
14 Jun 16:57:55 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
14 Jun 17:49:11 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
14 Jun 18:57:29 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
14 Jun 19:31:38 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
14 Jun 19:40:10 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
14 Jun 20:56:52 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
14 Jun 21:03:37 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
**14 Jun 21:16:53 ntpd[6771]: time reset -42.943002 s**  
14 Jun 21:20:34 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
14 Jun 21:21:39 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
15 Jun 04:57:42 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
15 Jun 05:14:47 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
15 Jun 06:23:10 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
15 Jun 06:57:17 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
15 Jun 09:13:47 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
15 Jun 11:13:19 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
15 Jun 12:04:32 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
15 Jun 12:21:38 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
15 Jun 13:12:54 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
15 Jun 13:55:37 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
15 Jun 15:55:11 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
15 Jun 16:12:14 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
15 Jun 20:59:18 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
15 Jun 21:21:16 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
15 Jun 21:54:18 ntpd[6771]: time reset -44.484272 s  
15 Jun 21:58:27 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
15 Jun 21:59:30 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
16 Jun 03:53:30 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
16 Jun 04:44:45 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
16 Jun 05:53:03 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
16 Jun 07:01:18 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
16 Jun 08:26:43 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
16 Jun 08:43:49 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
16 Jun 09:35:06 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
16 Jun 09:52:09 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
16 Jun 10:26:19 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
16 Jun 11:00:27 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
16 Jun 11:34:37 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
16 Jun 11:51:41 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
16 Jun 12:42:59 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
16 Jun 13:00:03 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
16 Jun 14:25:25 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
16 Jun 15:16:39 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
16 Jun 16:24:57 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
16 Jun 17:16:09 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
16 Jun 18:58:35 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
16 Jun 19:15:40 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
16 Jun 20:59:36 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
16 Jun 21:16:46 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
16 Jun 21:49:33 ntpd[6771]: time reset -46.023214 s  
16 Jun 21:52:53 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
16 Jun 21:53:57 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
17 Jun 03:12:33 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
17 Jun 03:29:36 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
17 Jun 04:20:49 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
17 Jun 05:12:01 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
17 Jun 07:28:37 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
17 Jun 08:02:43 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
17 Jun 09:28:07 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
17 Jun 10:02:13 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
17 Jun 11:10:31 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
17 Jun 11:27:36 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
17 Jun 17:01:37 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
17 Jun 17:18:42 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
17 Jun 20:09:32 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
17 Jun 21:01:48 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
17 Jun 21:01:48 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
17 Jun 21:19:34 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
17 Jun 21:52:12 ntpd[6771]: time reset -47.573538 s  
17 Jun 21:56:07 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
17 Jun 21:57:11 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
18 Jun 20:59:25 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
18 Jun 21:24:16 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
18 Jun 21:40:42 ntpd[6771]: time reset -49.122802 s  
18 Jun 21:44:59 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
18 Jun 21:46:03 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
19 Jun 09:30:18 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
19 Jun 11:12:46 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
19 Jun 11:46:55 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
19 Jun 12:38:10 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
19 Jun 14:03:33 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
19 Jun 14:20:36 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
19 Jun 15:11:48 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
19 Jun 15:45:55 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
19 Jun 16:20:04 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
19 Jun 16:37:08 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
19 Jun 17:11:19 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
19 Jun 17:28:24 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
19 Jun 19:36:29 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 4001  
19 Jun 19:53:33 ntpd[6771]: kernel time sync status change 0001  
19 Jun 21:02:58 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
19 Jun 21:20:53 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3  
19 Jun 21:37:16 ntpd[6771]: time reset -50.669270 s  
19 Jun 21:41:34 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to LOCAL(0), stratum 10  
19 Jun 21:42:07 ntpd[6771]: synchronized to 172.16.33.74, stratum 3
```

at this point i set up a cron job to run ntpdate every hour:

```
20 Jun 17:57:39 ntpdate[22583]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset -0.000421 sec  
20 Jun 18:01:01 ntpdate[22623]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000238 sec  
20 Jun 19:01:01 ntpdate[23046]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000753 sec  
20 Jun 20:01:02 ntpdate[23471]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000574 sec  
20 Jun 21:00:09 ntpdate[23890]: step time server 172.16.33.74 offset -52.211231 sec  
20 Jun 21:01:01 ntpdate[23909]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000033 sec  
20 Jun 22:01:01 ntpdate[24332]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000870 sec  
20 Jun 23:01:02 ntpdate[24757]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000499 sec  
21 Jun 00:01:01 ntpdate[25188]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.004997 sec  
21 Jun 01:01:01 ntpdate[25611]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset -0.000058 sec  
21 Jun 02:01:01 ntpdate[26035]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.001489 sec  
21 Jun 03:01:01 ntpdate[26460]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000491 sec  
21 Jun 04:01:01 ntpdate[27712]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000730 sec  
21 Jun 05:01:01 ntpdate[28270]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000841 sec  
21 Jun 06:01:01 ntpdate[28753]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000405 sec  
21 Jun 07:01:01 ntpdate[29177]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000474 sec  
21 Jun 08:01:01 ntpdate[29601]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000583 sec  
21 Jun 09:01:01 ntpdate[30024]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000660 sec  
21 Jun 10:01:01 ntpdate[30448]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000469 sec  
21 Jun 11:01:01 ntpdate[30872]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000605 sec  
21 Jun 12:01:01 ntpdate[31298]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000159 sec  
21 Jun 13:01:01 ntpdate[31721]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000539 sec  
21 Jun 14:01:01 ntpdate[32146]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000530 sec  
21 Jun 15:01:01 ntpdate[32570]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000560 sec  
21 Jun 16:01:01 ntpdate[583]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000820 sec  
21 Jun 17:01:01 ntpdate[1020]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000512 sec  
21 Jun 18:01:01 ntpdate[1445]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000239 sec  
21 Jun 19:01:01 ntpdate[1870]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000607 sec  
21 Jun 20:01:01 ntpdate[2294]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000717 sec  
21 Jun 21:01:02 ntpdate[2743]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000965 sec  
21 Jun 22:00:07 ntpdate[3174]: step time server 172.16.33.74 offset -53.812615 sec  
21 Jun 22:01:01 ntpdate[3196]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000024 sec  
21 Jun 23:01:01 ntpdate[3641]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000496 sec  
22 Jun 00:01:01 ntpdate[4133]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000920 sec  
22 Jun 01:01:01 ntpdate[4557]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000914 sec  
22 Jun 02:01:01 ntpdate[4980]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000702 sec  
22 Jun 03:01:01 ntpdate[5404]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000663 sec  
22 Jun 04:01:01 ntpdate[6631]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000608 sec  
22 Jun 05:01:01 ntpdate[7189]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000650 sec  
22 Jun 06:01:01 ntpdate[7613]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000895 sec  
22 Jun 07:01:01 ntpdate[8037]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000843 sec  
22 Jun 08:01:01 ntpdate[8462]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000559 sec  
22 Jun 09:01:01 ntpdate[8885]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000595 sec  
22 Jun 10:01:01 ntpdate[9309]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000617 sec  
22 Jun 11:01:01 ntpdate[9734]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000527 sec  
22 Jun 12:01:01 ntpdate[10158]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000546 sec  
22 Jun 13:01:01 ntpdate[10582]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000663 sec  
22 Jun 14:01:01 ntpdate[11006]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000790 sec  
22 Jun 15:01:01 ntpdate[11429]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000599 sec  
22 Jun 16:01:01 ntpdate[11854]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.001093 sec  
22 Jun 17:01:02 ntpdate[12277]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000444 sec  
22 Jun 18:01:01 ntpdate[12702]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.001054 sec  
22 Jun 19:01:01 ntpdate[13126]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000751 sec  
22 Jun 20:01:01 ntpdate[13550]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000832 sec  
22 Jun 21:01:01 ntpdate[13973]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.001551 sec  
22 Jun 22:00:06 ntpdate[14398]: step time server 172.16.33.74 offset -55.338569 sec  
22 Jun 22:01:01 ntpdate[14418]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000044 sec  
22 Jun 23:01:01 ntpdate[14845]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000949 sec  
23 Jun 00:01:01 ntpdate[15276]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000699 sec  
23 Jun 01:01:01 ntpdate[15700]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.001248 sec  
23 Jun 02:01:01 ntpdate[16123]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.001125 sec  
23 Jun 03:01:02 ntpdate[16547]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset -0.000017 sec  
23 Jun 04:01:01 ntpdate[17812]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000511 sec  
23 Jun 05:01:01 ntpdate[18371]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000460 sec  
23 Jun 06:01:01 ntpdate[18795]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000756 sec  
23 Jun 07:01:01 ntpdate[19219]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000756 sec  
23 Jun 08:01:01 ntpdate[19643]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000925 sec  
23 Jun 09:01:01 ntpdate[20066]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000770 sec  
23 Jun 10:01:01 ntpdate[20491]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000929 sec  
23 Jun 11:01:01 ntpdate[20915]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.001033 sec  
23 Jun 12:01:01 ntpdate[21339]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000177 sec  
23 Jun 13:01:01 ntpdate[21763]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000831 sec  
23 Jun 14:01:01 ntpdate[22187]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000671 sec  
23 Jun 15:01:01 ntpdate[22611]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000742 sec  
23 Jun 16:01:01 ntpdate[23034]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000978 sec  
23 Jun 17:01:01 ntpdate[23459]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000954 sec  
23 Jun 18:01:02 ntpdate[23882]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000546 sec  
23 Jun 19:01:01 ntpdate[24307]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.001156 sec  
23 Jun 20:01:01 ntpdate[24731]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000255 sec  
23 Jun 21:01:02 ntpdate[25155]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.001095 sec  
23 Jun 22:00:04 ntpdate[25579]: step time server 172.16.33.74 offset -56.876308 sec  
23 Jun 22:01:01 ntpdate[25600]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000056 sec  
23 Jun 23:01:01 ntpdate[26019]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.001729 sec  
24 Jun 00:01:02 ntpdate[26450]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000364 sec
```

then added cron every 5 minutes:

```
24 Jun 22:00:01 ntpdate[5200]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000874 sec  
24 Jun 22:01:01 ntpdate[5217]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset -0.000417 sec  
24 Jun 22:05:01 ntpdate[5250]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000289 sec  
24 Jun 22:10:01 ntpdate[5288]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset -0.000060 sec  
**24 Jun 22:14:02 ntpdate[5326]: step time server 172.16.33.74 offset -58.428188 sec**  
24 Jun 22:15:01 ntpdate[5332]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000055 sec  
**24 Jun 22:19:02 ntpdate[5372]: step time server 172.16.33.74 offset -58.458807 sec**  
24 Jun 22:20:02 ntpdate[5380]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000030 sec  
24 Jun 22:25:01 ntpdate[5416]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000078 sec  
24 Jun 22:30:01 ntpdate[5454]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000039 sec  
24 Jun 22:35:01 ntpdate[5490]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000058 sec  
24 Jun 22:40:01 ntpdate[5530]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000038 sec  
24 Jun 22:45:01 ntpdate[5566]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000055 sec  
24 Jun 22:50:01 ntpdate[5604]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000039 sec  
24 Jun 22:55:01 ntpdate[5640]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000060 sec  
24 Jun 23:01:01 ntpdate[5693]: adjust time server 172.16.33.74 offset 0.000043 sec
```

there are two times there the clock skips by almost 1 minute.
already checked other log files on the server and there is literally no data writen to any log other then ntp.log at this time.
there are no backup tasks etc. running at this time.
the server is a VMWARE virtual machine, and time synchronization with the host has been disabled.

server os is openfiler 2.3
uname -a
Linux xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 2.6.29.6-0.23.smp.gcc3.4.x86.i686 #1 SMP Mon Feb 8 16:28:15 GMT 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: Did you turn off the ntp daemon when you switched to using ntpdate? Have you read http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/techpaper/Timekeeping-In-VirtualMachines.pdf and/or http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006427